# Calling WCF Service from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net, wcf

I have a WCF webservice developed with .NET 4.0 which I need to be called by a Javascript client. I have been searching online for the best binding to use to make this possible. Most answers seems to point towards webhttp, but I am concerned as this is one of the lest secure bindings. What is the best way to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experience and understanding of "invoking wcf service from client side using jquery", i would say:

You can use either of webhttp or basichttp binding if need to invoke using jquery/javascript (surely basichttp better choice over webhttp here).

One person even wrote an article on codeproject where mentioned that using jquery one can even invoke wshttp bidning based wcf, I have not tried it myself, so not sure about it but if you need to expose your service with wshttp, then can refer this link on CP:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311908/Calling-WCF-service-exposed-with-different-binding

In my opinion i would say:
if there is no business need to expose service as rest one, then don't go for webhttp, Again if your client app is NOT a .net app and if there is no need to have security in place, then you can avoid wshttp totally, so per this **i would say go for basichttp** bidning, where you get interoperable service and can even add security in future, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Quick testing your WCF webservice you can install "Advance REST client", it's available for Chrome/Firefox.
In order to integrate with your JS client app, you can use jQuery http get post depending upon your WCF verb. Alternatively, you can also use Angular.JS for the same, e.g., $http.get

For security you can secure your service endpoints in .net

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301.aspx) which specify different security configurations you can use in wcf.

What is your javascript client? is it running in browser?