# consuming wcf web service using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I have created one wcf and is running locally in my machine. In the same project i have created a html page calling this wcf web service using ajax.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "wbsvc.svc/calendar",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    processData: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        var data = msg.d;
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

calendar is the method in webservice.
Error is

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) in wcf using ajax http://localhost:65029/wbsvc.svc/calendar?callback=jQuery110108707461392041296_1379052209564
```

What i am missing here.

Interface is

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Model.calenderinfo[] calendar();
```

Comment: You should post your service code, service configuration etc. if you want help. You are also using the POST method, but you don't include any data.

Comment: Its means you are not passing Parameter or some required resource

Comment: It's still better to use "GET" in your case, since you only query for an array of calendar info objects

Comment: you can see my answer here, this will give idea of different ways of doing call to wcf from jquery, one of those will surely suit you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18735160/2206468

Answer (score 0):

jsonp is for crossDomain, just try json

Comment: I'm not experienced in svc, but are you sure that it returns result in json format?

Comment: how can i check this...even i have not worked on svc earlier...i used to work on asmx

Comment: Well, before setting dataType into json just try it as html,and make success: function(msg) {alert(msg);} If it works, it means that problem is in formatting $.ajax({
    url: "wbsvc.svc/calendar",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (msg) {
      alert(msg);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});

Comment: Still says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) in wcf using ajax http://localhost:65029/wbsvc.svc/calendar?callback=jQuery110108707461392041296_1379052209564  ?

Comment: have you tried to enter http://localhost:65029/wbsvc.svc/calendar page with browser? If your browser can't open this page, it means that you have to learn svc better

Comment: May be that's because it doesn't return response via ajax, I have no other idea, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype to Json.

```
dataType: "json"
```

I think the url for your wcf service is worng.
Before sending the request, try to open Chrome Developer tool, or Firbug on Firefox, you can see the Request URL.

Now if your request URL is `http://localhost/myproject/wbsvc.svc/calendar`
 then type in `http://localhost/myproject/wbsvc.svc` in  browser , if you are able to see the
WSDL page, then your URL is correct.
Otherwise you need to give correct url in URL parameter.